# Question asked in nbhm exam 2022

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Q.Let n be the smallest positive integer that has 2022 as a factor and has exactly 2022 factors (counting
both 1 and n as factors of n). Let d be the largest positive integer such that $2^d$ divides n.
What is d?

My approach:

Since $2022=2\times 3\times 337$, we know that $n$ must be divisible by all three of these primes. Let $n = 2^a \cdot 3^b \cdot 337^c$, where $a,b,c$ are positive integers. Then we know that $n$ has $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$ factors.

Since $n$ has exactly $2022$ factors, we must have
(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=2022.

Now please help me to complete the solution

Comment: Note that $n$ is to be the *smallest* positive integer which meets the criteria, so what should the exponents' sizes be compared to the prime values?

Comment: since n has to be the smallest positive integer of such type: a +1=337, b+1=3 c+1=2. I think you can take it further from there

Comment: @KKT from here we can conclude that d =336 right?

Comment: @sonu yes we can conclude d=336

Comment: You should use "divisors" instead of "factors".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, $2022 = 2 × 3 × 337$
Since,
$2022|n$
$\implies 2022 = 2^a × 3^b × 337^c$

Also note, in order to minimise $n$, we have to work with only these three primes. Hence, $$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) = 2022$$

Now, $n$ is minimum if
$$a+1=337$$
$$b+1=3$$
$$c+1=2$$
$\implies n = 2^{336} × 3^2 × 337$

From this, it is perfectly clear that the value of $d$ is $336$